# Issue retrieving specific xml data

Tags: php, xml

For the last several hours I've been trying to retrieve specific data from an XML file https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?title=1

The data which I'm trying to retrieve is located with type "Genres", Ideally I've been trying to place "Genres" into a loop because of the different XML files having a different number of "Genres".

I've been reading the XML and PHP manual as well as Googling to find a possible solution but I've drawn a blank, if anyone is able to point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it, thank you.

I've tried to use an if statement but the expected results was not what was displayed

```
$url = "https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?title=1";

$result = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($result->anime as $data) {

foreach ($result->anime as $data) {
    if ($a['type'] = "Genres") {
        foreach ($data->info as $info) {
            $a = $info->attributes();
            echo $a['type']." : ".$a['src'] .$info. "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to output to be anything between the > and < brackets that has the type="Genres", the expected output should say "action drama science fiction" but the actual output is all the data from "Picture" to "Official website" from the XML file.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` in your `if` condition

Comment: You use `$a['type']` without ever using `$a` before, you also have 2 `foreach()` loops with the same variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few bugs in your code, but you can also achieve what you want without having to test for each attribute yourself.  Using XPath allows you to retrieve a list of the elements you want.

This code uses `//info[@type='Genres']` which means any `<info>` node which has an attribute `type` equal to `Genres`.  The call to `xpath()` will return a list of just the matching elements, so no need to test anything more, just output the information your after...

```
$url = "https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?title=1";

$result = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($result->xpath("//info[@type='Genres']") as $data) {
    echo $data['type']." : " .(string)$data. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate this.

Comment: at the bottom of the xml file is information under credit, could you confirm please what the correct xpath in selecting the credit would be, I've tried `//anime//credit` and it's getting the gid of the six entries, but I've been unable to select the task, company id, and record

`foreach ($result->xpath("//anime//credit") as $data) {
 echo "gid : ".$data['gid']." task : ". $data['task']."id : ".$data['id']." : " .(string)$data. "<br>";
}`

Comment: When you are accessing a child element (i.e. `<task>`, you need to use object notation - `$data->task`, similar for the company, you want the attribute of a child element which would be `$data->company['id']`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.